# CSS class specificity order

Tags: css, primefaces

I have defined my own CSS class:

```
.my-ui-table td {
border-width: 1px;
border: 0;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-style: hidden;
border-color: inherit;
}
```

Default PrimeFaces css defines its own class that is being applied to :

```
.ui-panelgrid td {
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: inherit;
padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

Both classes are being applied to table:

```
<table class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget my-ui-table" role="grid">...</table>
```

When Chrome renders said table the border-style from ui-panelgrid class takes precedence over border-style defined in my-ui-table class. I have been reading up on CSS specificity and the way it seems to be specificity is the same for both classes definitions, so the one specified last in class="" attribute should win. Why isnt this happening?

EDIT: HTML head tag:

```
<head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/do/javax.faces.resource/my.css?ln=css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/do/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces">
</head>
```

.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not which one comes first in your class="..." order that matters, it's which one is written last in your css rules that matters. That's why its called cascading style sheets, cuz the last relevant rule, with equal or higher specificity will be applied. So if all your rules are in an external sheet and if they have equal specificity, the last one will be applied. But inline/ internal styles take precedence over external ones. (Though this doesn't mean you should use them)

Comment: These CSS rules are in different files - does that mean the order in which files are loaded matters?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the second file will take precedence.

Comment: Final clarification: do I have to swap the order of <link> tags in my header to fix this? I will have to do some digging in order to change this as the header is autogenerated, and dont want to do all this for nothing :) Thanks!

Comment: There must be something else going on then ... check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/dfJNV/

Comment: By header do you mean <head>?

Comment: And, if you don't want to fix it this way, you can always just up the specificity of the rule you want to take precedence.

Comment: Yes, <HEAD> tag within the html. Sorry for confusion. To me the jsfiddle example just confirms that rule which comes last in CSS will take precedence. If I cant change the order in which CSS files are loaded what would be the best way to up the specificity? The only way I see is component ID but that class will be applied to many different component IDs. Thanks!

Comment: Second in the css, or in the second linked stylesheet means the same thing. btw.